# Numba not speeding up function

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numba

I have some code I'm trying to speed up with numba. I've done some reading on the topic, but I haven't been able to figure it out 100%.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import seaborn as sns
from numba import jit, vectorize, float64, autojit
sns.set(context='talk', style='ticks', font_scale=1.2, rc={'figure.figsize': (6.5, 5.5), 'xtick.direction': 'in', 'ytick.direction': 'in'})

#%% constraints
x_min = 0                               # death below this
x_max = 20                              # maximum weight
t_max = 100                             # maximum time
foraging_efficiencies = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)               # potential foraging efficiencies
R = 10.0                                    # Resource level

#%% make the body size and time categories
body_sizes = np.arange(x_min, x_max+1)
time_steps = np.arange(t_max)

#%% parameter functions
@jit
def metabolic_fmr(x, u,temp):                           # metabolic cost function
    fmr = 0.125*(2**(0.2*temp))*(1 + 0.5*u) + x*0.1
    return fmr

def intake_dist(u):                         # intake stochastic function (returns a vector)
    g = st.binom.pmf(np.arange(R+1), R, u)
    return g

@jit
def mass_gain(x, u, temp):                      # mass gain function (returns a vector)
    x_prime = x - metabolic_fmr(x, u,temp) + np.arange(R+1)
    x_prime = np.minimum(x_prime, x_max)
    x_prime = np.maximum(x_prime, 0)
    return x_prime

@jit
def prob_attack(P):                         # probability of an attack
    p_a = 0.02*P
    return p_a

@jit
def prob_see(u):                            # probability of not seeing an attack
    p_s = 1-(1-u)**0.3
    return p_s

@jit
def prob_lethal(x):                         # probability of lethality given a successful attack
    p_l = 0.5*np.exp(-0.05*x) 
    return p_l

@jit
def prob_mort(P, u, x):
    p_m = prob_attack(P)*prob_see(u)*prob_lethal(x)
    return np.minimum(p_m, 1)

#%% terminal fitness function
@jit
def terminal_fitness(x):
    t_f = 15.0*x/(x+5.0)
    return t_f

#%% linear interpolation function
@jit
def linear_interpolation(x, F, t):
    floor = x.astype(int)
    delta_c = x-floor
    ceiling = floor + 1
    ceiling[ceiling>x_max] = x_max
    floor[floor<x_min] = x_min
    interpolated_F = (1-delta_c)*F[floor,t] + (delta_c)*F[ceiling,t]
    return interpolated_F

#%% solver
@jit
def solver_jit(P, temp):
    F = np.zeros((len(body_sizes), len(time_steps)))            # Expected fitness
    F[:,-1] = terminal_fitness(body_sizes)              # expected terminal fitness for every body size
    V = np.zeros((len(foraging_efficiencies), len(body_sizes), len(time_steps)))        # Fitness for each foraging effort
    D = np.zeros((len(body_sizes), len(time_steps)))            # Decision
    for t in range(t_max-1)[::-1]:
        for x in range(x_min+1, x_max+1):               # iterate over every body size except dead
            for i in range(len(foraging_efficiencies)):     # iterate over every possible foraging efficiency
                u = foraging_efficiencies[i]
                g_u = intake_dist(u)                # calculate the distribution of intakes
                xp = mass_gain(x, u, temp)          # calculate the mass gain
                p_m = prob_mort(P, u, x)            # probability of mortality
                V[i,x,t] = (1 - p_m)*(linear_interpolation(xp, F, t+1)*g_u).sum()       # Fitness calculation
            vmax = V[:,x,t].max()
            idx = np.argwhere(V[:,x,t]==vmax).min()
            D[x,t] = foraging_efficiencies[idx]
            F[x,t] = vmax
    return D, F

def solver_norm(P, temp):
    F = np.zeros((len(body_sizes), len(time_steps)))            # Expected fitness
    F[:,-1] = terminal_fitness(body_sizes)              # expected terminal fitness for every body size
    V = np.zeros((len(foraging_efficiencies), len(body_sizes), len(time_steps)))        # Fitness for each foraging effort
    D = np.zeros((len(body_sizes), len(time_steps)))            # Decision
    for t in range(t_max-1)[::-1]:
        for x in range(x_min+1, x_max+1):               # iterate over every body size except dead
            for i in range(len(foraging_efficiencies)):     # iterate over every possible foraging efficiency
                u = foraging_efficiencies[i]
                g_u = intake_dist(u)                # calculate the distribution of intakes
                xp = mass_gain(x, u, temp)          # calculate the mass gain
                p_m = prob_mort(P, u, x)            # probability of mortality
                V[i,x,t] = (1 - p_m)*(linear_interpolation(xp, F, t+1)*g_u).sum()       # Fitness calculation
            vmax = V[:,x,t].max()
            idx = np.argwhere(V[:,x,t]==vmax).min()
            D[x,t] = foraging_efficiencies[idx]
            F[x,t] = vmax
    return D, F
```

The individual jit functions tend to be much faster than the un-jitted ones. For example, prob_mort is about 600% faster once it has been run through jit. However, the solver itself isn't much faster:

```
In [3]: %timeit -n 10 solver_jit(200, 25)
10 loops, best of 3: 3.94 s per loop

In [4]: %timeit -n 10 solver_norm(200, 25)
10 loops, best of 3: 4.09 s per loop
```

I know some functions can't be jitted, so I replaced the st.binom.pmf function with a custom jit function and that actually slowed down the time to about 17s per loop, over 5x slower. Presumably because the scipy functions are, at this point, heavily optimized.

So I suspect the slowness is either in the linear_interpolate function or somewhere in the solver code outside of the jitted functions (because at one point I un-jitted all the functions and ran solver_norm and got the same time). Any thoughts on where the slow part would be and how to speed it up?

**UPDATE**

Here's the binomial code I used in an attempt to speed up jit

```
@jit
def factorial(n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*factorial(n-1)

@vectorize([float64(float64,float64,float64)])
def binom(k, n, p):
    binom_coef = factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k))
    pmf = binom_coef*p**k*(1-p)**(n-k)
    return pmf

@jit
def intake_dist(u):                         # intake stochastic function (returns a vector)
    g = binom(np.arange(R+1), R, u)
    return g
```

**UPDATE 2**
I tried running my binomial code in nopython mode and found out I was doing it wrong because it was recursive. Upon fixing that by changing code to:

```
@jit(int64(int64), nopython=True)
def factorial(nn):
    res = 1
    for ii in range(2, nn + 1):
        res *= ii
    return res

@vectorize([float64(float64,float64,float64)], nopython=True)
def binom(k, n, p):
    binom_coef = factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k))
    pmf = binom_coef*p**k*(1-p)**(n-k)
    return pmf
```

the solver now runs at

```
In [34]: %timeit solver_jit(200, 25)
1 loop, best of 3: 921 ms per loop
```

which is about 3.5x faster. However, solver_jit() and solver_norm() still run at the same pace, which means there is some code outside the jit functions slowing it down.

Comment: Can you post your custom `binom.pmf` function? I'm guessing that the reason why you're not getting any improvement using the jit is that `intake_dist` is in your innermost loop and this cannot be jitted, so you're using "object mode" in your solver.

Comment: If the `binom.pmf` is the bottleneck, you might try wrapping the rmath version and calling it via cffi as I describe in this blog post: https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/calling-c-libraries-numba-using-cffi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make a few changes to your code to make it so the jit version could compile completely in `nopython` mode. On my laptop, this results in:

```
%timeit solver_jit(200, 25)
1 loop, best of 3: 50.9 ms per loop

%timeit solver_norm(200, 25)
1 loop, best of 3: 192 ms per loop
```

For reference, I'm using Numba 0.27.0. I'll admit that Numba's compilation errors still make it difficult to identify what is going on, but since I've been playing with it for a while, I've built up an intuition for what needs to be fixed. The complete code is below, but here is the list of changes I made:

- In `linear_interpolation` change `x.astype(int)` to `x.astype(np.int64)` so it could compile in `nopython` mode.
- In the solver, use `np.sum` as a function and not a method of an array.
- `np.argwhere` isn't supported. Write a custom loop.

There are probably some further optimizations that could be made, but this gives an initial speed-up.

The full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import seaborn as sns
from numba import jit, vectorize, float64, autojit, njit
sns.set(context='talk', style='ticks', font_scale=1.2, rc={'figure.figsize': (6.5, 5.5), 'xtick.direction': 'in', 'ytick.direction': 'in'})

#%% constraints
x_min = 0                               # death below this
x_max = 20                              # maximum weight
t_max = 100                             # maximum time
foraging_efficiencies = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)               # potential foraging efficiencies
R = 10.0                                    # Resource level

#%% make the body size and time categories
body_sizes = np.arange(x_min, x_max+1)
time_steps = np.arange(t_max)

#%% parameter functions
@njit
def metabolic_fmr(x, u,temp):                           # metabolic cost function
    fmr = 0.125*(2**(0.2*temp))*(1 + 0.5*u) + x*0.1
    return fmr

@njit()
def factorial(nn):
    res = 1
    for ii in range(2, nn + 1):
        res *= ii
    return res

@vectorize([float64(float64,float64,float64)], nopython=True)
def binom(k, n, p):
    binom_coef = factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k))
    pmf = binom_coef*p**k*(1-p)**(n-k)
    return pmf

@njit
def intake_dist(u):                         # intake stochastic function (returns a vector)
    g = binom(np.arange(R+1), R, u)
    return g

@njit
def mass_gain(x, u, temp):                      # mass gain function (returns a vector)
    x_prime = x - metabolic_fmr(x, u,temp) + np.arange(R+1)
    x_prime = np.minimum(x_prime, x_max)
    x_prime = np.maximum(x_prime, 0)
    return x_prime

@njit
def prob_attack(P):                         # probability of an attack
    p_a = 0.02*P
    return p_a

@njit
def prob_see(u):                            # probability of not seeing an attack
    p_s = 1-(1-u)**0.3
    return p_s

@njit
def prob_lethal(x):                         # probability of lethality given a successful attack
    p_l = 0.5*np.exp(-0.05*x) 
    return p_l

@njit
def prob_mort(P, u, x):
    p_m = prob_attack(P)*prob_see(u)*prob_lethal(x)
    return np.minimum(p_m, 1)

#%% terminal fitness function
@njit
def terminal_fitness(x):
    t_f = 15.0*x/(x+5.0)
    return t_f

#%% linear interpolation function
@njit
def linear_interpolation(x, F, t):
    floor = x.astype(np.int64)
    delta_c = x-floor
    ceiling = floor + 1
    ceiling[ceiling>x_max] = x_max
    floor[floor<x_min] = x_min
    interpolated_F = (1-delta_c)*F[floor,t] + (delta_c)*F[ceiling,t]
    return interpolated_F

#%% solver
@njit
def solver_jit(P, temp):
    F = np.zeros((len(body_sizes), len(time_steps)))            # Expected fitness
    F[:,-1] = terminal_fitness(body_sizes)              # expected terminal fitness for every body size
    V = np.zeros((len(foraging_efficiencies), len(body_sizes), len(time_steps)))        # Fitness for each foraging effort
    D = np.zeros((len(body_sizes), len(time_steps)))            # Decision
    for t in range(t_max-2,-1,-1):
        for x in range(x_min+1, x_max+1):               # iterate over every body size except dead
            for i in range(len(foraging_efficiencies)):     # iterate over every possible foraging efficiency
                u = foraging_efficiencies[i]
                g_u = intake_dist(u)                # calculate the distribution of intakes
                xp = mass_gain(x, u, temp)          # calculate the mass gain
                p_m = prob_mort(P, u, x)            # probability of mortality
                V[i,x,t] = (1 - p_m)*np.sum((linear_interpolation(xp, F, t+1)*g_u))       # Fitness calculation
            vmax = V[:,x,t].max()

            for k in xrange(V.shape[0]):
                if V[k,x,t] == vmax:
                    idx = k
                    break
            #idx = np.argwhere(V[:,x,t]==vmax).min()
            D[x,t] = foraging_efficiencies[idx]
            F[x,t] = vmax
    return D, F

def solver_norm(P, temp):
    F = np.zeros((len(body_sizes), len(time_steps)))            # Expected fitness
    F[:,-1] = terminal_fitness(body_sizes)              # expected terminal fitness for every body size
    V = np.zeros((len(foraging_efficiencies), len(body_sizes), len(time_steps)))        # Fitness for each foraging effort
    D = np.zeros((len(body_sizes), len(time_steps)))            # Decision
    for t in range(t_max-1)[::-1]:
        for x in range(x_min+1, x_max+1):               # iterate over every body size except dead
            for i in range(len(foraging_efficiencies)):     # iterate over every possible foraging efficiency
                u = foraging_efficiencies[i]
                g_u = intake_dist(u)                # calculate the distribution of intakes
                xp = mass_gain(x, u, temp)          # calculate the mass gain
                p_m = prob_mort(P, u, x)            # probability of mortality
                V[i,x,t] = (1 - p_m)*(linear_interpolation(xp, F, t+1)*g_u).sum()       # Fitness calculation
            vmax = V[:,x,t].max()
            idx = np.argwhere(V[:,x,t]==vmax).min()
            D[x,t] = foraging_efficiencies[idx]
            F[x,t] = vmax
    return D, F
```

Comment: Thanks! This sped up my code, going from 4.02 s per run to 320 ms per run! The trick with linear interpolation, using np.int64, was a hangup for me because I didn't know what the issue was that was preventing it from compiling in no python mode. That alone reduced the time by 3 seconds. I also knew that argwhere wasn't supported, but didn't have custom code to replace it. Thanks for the help! 320 ms is a huge improvement!

Answer (score 0):

As said, there is likely some code that is falling back to object mode. I just wanted to add that you can use njit instead of jit to disable object mode. That will help diagnose what code is the culprit.